# Light and dark themes disappeared without any apparent reason

Tags: themes, appearance

As described. I used light and dark default ubuntu desktops themes since years ago and now they disappeared without any reason.

If I go to settings appearance they do not appear on the "theme" list any more. Only Adwaita shows up and is selected (what I never did).

Any clue how to restore the light and dark themes?

Ubuntu desktop 18.10